# Динамическое значение атрибута в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

В jQuery значение переменной **number** считывается с **value**   поля **input** в котором атрибут **name** в данном примере равен 2, вот так:

```
var number = $("input[name=2]").val();
```

Как сделать чтобы в данной контструкции значение **name** сравнивалось бы с другой переменной, как то вот-так:

```
var num = 2;
var number = $("input[name=num]").val();
```

*(разумеется, последний код нерабочий)*

Comment: Это же элементарная работа со строками

Comment: Если не париться на счет древних браузеров или использовать Babel, то в js уже есть удобные механизмы.

`let number = $(\`input[name=${num}]\`).val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно Вам такой вариант подойдет

```js
var num = 2;
var number = $("input[name=" + num + "]").val();
console.log(number);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input name="2" value="val">
  </input>
</div>
```

Comment: так просто, аж стыдно! Спасибо!